# How behind the scenes spring boot application connects with mongodb and its Document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, configuration

When I am connecting to docker instance with mongodb it is connecting successfully but not able to fetch the data from the specific document. When I am saving the Customer data it saves but where it is getting stored is unknown. All operations like findAll findByFirstName findByLastName are giving null

I followed https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ but I could not understand behind the scenes how it is connecting with mongodb and its configuration

No error messages, code is being compiled and executed successfully

Comment: If you have followed [Link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) properly then it should not happen. It is possible that you may misunderstand the one of step and facing an issue I would suggest you verify each and every step you have performed.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of one part-->
Since I have not used the same package for MongoRepository it was not picking the right document. So the learning here is if you use a different package other than your @SpringBootApplication Entry class then you need to use @EnableMongoRepositories that tells Spring that if it doesn't find the repositories then scan the other packages as well.

I am still researching how to change the default database from "test"(default) to the one that I am using in my mongodb instance

Answer (score 0):

I got the other part of my question:
How to change the default db settings pointing to "test". Following annotations which are used for the mongo configuration:
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(ignoreUnknownFields = false, prefix = "spring.data.mongodb")

and importantly AbstractMongoConfiguration abstract class that contains abstract methods for configuring mongodb params

```
package usecase;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(ignoreUnknownFields = false, prefix = "spring.data.mongodb")
public class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "mydb";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    }
}
```